# Sort list of lists of lists based on sum of Nth element of inner lists

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

If I have:

```
a = [[['Q1', 20], ['R1', 14]], [['Q2', 18], ['R2', 17]], [['Q3', 24], ['R1', 14]]]
```

how do I sort `a` so that I get:

```
[[['Q3', 24], ['R1', 14]], [['Q2', 18], ['R2', 17]], [['Q1', 20], ['R1', 14]]]
```

because the sum of the second elements of the lists within those tuples are 38, 35 and 34, respectively (in the second, sorted version)? Also, there has to be a better way to have this all organized so a suggestion regarding that would be gladly accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with `sum`:

```
a = [[['Q1', 20], ['R1', 14]], [['Q2', 18], ['R2', 17]], [['Q3', 24], ['R1', 14]]]
new_a = sorted(a, key=lambda x:sum(c for _, c in x), reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
[[['Q3', 24], ['R1', 14]], [['Q2', 18], ['R2', 17]], [['Q1', 20], ['R1', 14]]]
```

Edit: to remove listings that sum to a value greater than a specified variable, you can use a list comprehension:

```
final_result = [i for i in new_a if sum(c for _, c in i) < 36]
```

Output:

```
[[['Q2', 18], ['R2', 17]], [['Q1', 20], ['R1', 14]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now I'm wondering how I would be able to cut out certain pairs which sum to above a certain number, say 36 in this example.

Comment: Thanks so much this is super helpful!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use the `key` arg + `reverse=True` from `sorted`.

```
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: sum(i[1] for i in x), reverse=True)

[[['Q3', 24], ['R1', 14]], [['Q2', 18], ['R2', 17]], [['Q1', 20], ['R1', 14]]]
```